# Pages are corrupted once using include(404.php); after sending http_response_code(404)

Tags: php, .htaccess, character-encoding, include, http-response-codes

I have set up a mod_rewrite in a sub-directory (NOT root directory) using .htaccess file, code as follows:

```
#Enable the mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

#Rewrite condition as follows, if the URL matches a read directory, file or link then don't do the rewrite.
ReweiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ReweiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ReweiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#The Rewrite rule is as follows:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The plan is if the user enters a wrong URL a 404 error to be returned. I have used the following PHP code that worked with me perfectly in a PHP file located in the root directory.

```
http_response_code(404);
include("404.php");
die();
```

However, the result is not expected, the page appears as follows:

> L���O�����;�γ}��Li[zf˫9]�!i$a����_��ZBU)��,[@y�O$�������'*��3�I�m���K���J,b����u�������&�����Im���:�=�A���A���$�d&:����4�`L8�?��ѾQ|��~��"֡2\�Uq�^��~ӫ�=��hO�\uJ��ӳ��0.�L�e��HgtX7��3:l����x�~�@�!Jgt�z3
> ����ϼ�T�$O�'�6�~�������.��s~A�e*�� e�=ذ_2����wfԢ��,��,-�
> )�3�3S��Ll���u��\��%[�5['�U
> Ϸ�Ƅ3g�5�S��q�|�&-G����-6��O<��uƛ.��y���w�v(W*���Yʁ��7��r�j3q������c�~�g��Yฺ"$߼ˊ�1cv����;�C��Ҹ3�
> h��<�>:��5xޡsP/u㾾

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the .htaccess, but I have put everything that I thought is related.

Please note that both pages either the one that calls 404.php and the latter has the `charset=UTF-8`

Comment: "has the charset=UTF-8" - But are the files actually saved with a UTF-8 encoding? Presumably your `index.php` file (located in the subdirectory as well) does more than simply serve a 404? Presumably the URL you are requesting includes the subdirectory in question?

Comment: Index.php is in the subdirectory along with 404.php, the browser says files are UTF-8. If http_response_code is removed, then all files are served correctly. The issue is somewhere around it, maybe has something with .htaccees because I do exactly this in the root directly, and things are perfect.

Comment: "the browser says files are UTF-8" - the browser just tells you what encoding is being used to render the response, they don't tell you the encoding of the underlying file. I don't see how `http_response_code()` could have anything to do with this? (But if removing that statement appears to resolve the issue, what makes you think it's an issue with `.htaccess`?) Can you confirm that the `.htaccess` file as posted is the actually `.htaccess` file you are using? The `.htaccess` file you've posted is syntactically invalid as it has an erroneous _space_ in the last directive.

Comment: Actually, the space entered was a typo. Yes, this is the .htaccess that I'm using and makes the rewrite rules correctly.  removing http_response_code() resolves the issue, but I need to use it as I want the page to return 404 error, if there's another way (in addition to header() which has the same result) then I'd be grateful to know. I suspect the .htaccess because pages in the root folder have the same code in terms of http_response_code() and then include(), and everything is okay, so the only difference I see here is the .htaccess. Any ideas about what should be done?

Comment: But don't you have the same `.htaccess` file in the root also? (Why do you need this `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory?) To clarify, presumably your `index.php` file is doing more than simply serving a 404? There's nothing wrong with your (updated) `.htaccess` file.

Comment: The .htaccees file in the subdirectory makes different rewrite rules that's why it is there. So if it doesn't have an issue what would cause such a problem? You know there's another file included in index.php, and that one is able to return 404 code with no encoding issue. Is there something to start looking at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249020/discussion-between-mostafa-and-mrwhite).